# Sequelize save Data in belongsToMany created Table and Read from it(Solution at the End)

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am using for my Backend Node.js,Express.js and Sequelize for the connection to the Database.
I have a n:m Relationship between Tasks and Keys.
[image: schema]

Tasks and Keys is created by me and TaskKey through Sequelize with:

**Backend**

```
    // Tasks n:m Keys
    db.DictKey.belongsToMany(db.Task, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey:'key_id'});
    db.Task.belongsToMany(db.DictKey, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey: 'task_id'});
```

Now if I create a new Task on the

**frontend**

```
$scope.create = () => {
    this.$http.post('/api/tasks', {
        user_id: $scope.selectUser,
        lang_id: $scope.selectLang,
        name: $scope.newTask
    });
}
```

I want to send with that request an Array of all Keys the User selected.

In the Backend it should add an entry to `TaskKeys` for the new Task for every DictKey sent.
For example

Table Task:

```
ID | some values
1  | some values | this is the new task created
```

Send Keys in Array[2,5,6]

TaskKey / in the same moment create in this Table the Dependant Keys

```
TaskID | KeyID
1      | 2
1      | 5
1      | 6
```

How can I achieve that ?

After that I would like to show a Task.
Taking the Example before.
Get task where id = 1
ng-repeat all datas and as well get all Keys thanks to the Table TaskKey.

I could not find a Example which explains that and the only solution I have at the moment is at the front end with `$http.post(taskkey)` with a `foreach` for every key in the Table `TaskKey`. But later in the Live System there would be over 1000 keys, so this isn't an acceptable solution.
Is there a good solution for that for backend?

**Edit1:**

```
...    working fine
$scope.create = () => {
            this.$http.post('/api/tasks', {
              task:{
              user_id: $scope.selectUser,
              lang_id: $scope.selectLang,
              name: $scope.newTask
            },
            keys:[1,2,3,4,5]
          });
    ...
 ... 
// Creates a new Task in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  return Task.create(req.body.task)
  .then(function(task){
    return task.addTaskKeys(req.body.keys);//throws 500error
    //console.log(req.body.keys);//working fine getting the Keys
  })
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
...
```

Reading the docs [belongsToManyDoc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/) doesnt help much because no Examples or Detailed Explained.
Ive tried several things like:

- addTask/addTasks/addTaskKeys/addKey as in doc explained for adding an association
- createTask/createKey/createTaskKeys for creating an association

In my backend I dont have any Functions for TaskKeys only for Tasks and Keys. But as I understood I dont need any for TaskKeys because with

```
 // Tasks n:m Keys
    db.DictKey.belongsToMany(db.Task, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey:'key_id'});
    db.Task.belongsToMany(db.DictKey, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey: 'task_id'});
```

creating Middle Table there is an association between Tasks and Keys. So normally add/create should just work and it should add instances in TaskKeys.

```
 export function create(req, res) {
      return Task.create(req.body.task)
      .then(function(task){
        return task.addTaskKeys(req.body.keys);//throws 500error
```

with task.addTaskKeys adding Associations with the just created Task=> task_id

with req.body.keys giving him the Keys =>key_id
If I take the Example from Doc change to minde DB:

```
... example
    Project.create({ id: 11 }).then(function (project) {
      user.addProjects([project, 12]);
    });
... mine
return Task.create(req.body.task)
  .then(function(task){
    return DictKey.addTasks([task,{key_id : 1}]);//still error
  })//DictKey.addTask(task,1); still error
```

Reading the BelongsToMany Association and Quoting it:

> user.addProject(project, { status: 'started' })
>   By default the code will add projectId and userId to the UserProjects table

Trying out creating with Associations:

> http://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/associations/#creating-elements-of-a-hasmany-or-belongstomany-association
>   Sorry not allowed to post more as 1 Link.

```
export function create(req, res) {
  return Task.create({
    name: req.body.task.name,
    user_id: req.body.task.user_id,
    lang_id: req.body.task.lang_id,
    key_id:[req.body.keys]
  },{
    include: [DictKey]
  })
```

No Error but only Creating Task not TaskKeys....
So what Iam doing wrong whole time?

**Edit2:**
For Testing I inserted Data in the Table TaskKeys by Myself in MsSql.
TaskKey / Self Created Datas with SqlQuery

```
TaskID | KeyID
1      | 1
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 4
2      | 5
```

getting it from my **frontend**

```
this.$http.get('/api/tasks/' +2 )
            .then(response => {
              this.Tasks = response.data;
              console.log(this.Tasks);
            });
```

**backend**

```
// Gets a single Task from the DB
export function show(req, res) {
  return Task.findAll({
    where: {
      _id: req.params.id
    },
    include: [{
      model: DictKey
    }]
  })
    .then(handleEntityNotFound(res))
    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

ConsoleOutput:

```
[Object]
Object
_id:2 // the searched TaskId= 2 => right
dict_Keys:Array[2] // the Dependant 2 KeyIds => right
```

So the table which is created is working fine.
The Question is now only why adding through Backend with addKey is not working by doing the same as in the Example.
Trying the Example to check Associations:

```
// Creates a new Task in the DB
export function create(req, res) {
  Task.create({
  name: req.body.task.name,
  user_id: req.body.task.user_id,
  lang_id: req.body.task.lang_id
}).then(function(task) {
    return DictKey.create({ name:req.body.task.name,notice:req.body.task.name, user_id:req.body.task.user_id })
    .then(function(key) {
      return task.hasDictKey(key).then(function(result) {
        // result would be false
        return task.addDictKey(key).then(function() {
          return task.hasDictKey(key).then(function(result) {
            // result would be true
          })
        })
      })
    })
  })
```

Throws task.hasDictKey is not a function

```
db.Task.create({
  name: 'test',
  user_id: 266,
  lang_id: 9,
  key_id:[1,2]
},{
  include: [db.DictKey]
})
```

Throws dict_Keys is not associated to Task
So it means they are not Connected together? BUt Reading data and Inserting Data in the Database is working?

Just Adding now the Example of Sequelize:

```
var Usert = db.sequelize.define('usert', {})
var Project = db.sequelize.define('project', {})
var UserProjects = db.sequelize.define('userProjects', {
    status: Sequelize.STRING
})

Usert.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.belongsToMany(Usert, { through: UserProjects })
Usert.addProject(Project, { status: 'started' })//addProject is not a Function // for real ? now not even their own is not working? :/
```

**Answer**
By Reading the Docs I thought with

```
// Tasks n:m Keys
db.DictKey.belongsToMany(db.Task, { through: TaskKeys , foreignKey:'key_id',otherKey:'task_id'});
db.Task.belongsToMany(db.DictKey, { through: TaskKeys , foreignKey: 'task_id',otherKey: 'key_id'});
```

it would automatically generate add/set/get/create Task for DictKey and add/set/get/create DictKey for Task.

But

> Naming strategy
>
> By default sequelize will use the model name (the name passed to
>   sequelize.define) to figure out the name of the model when used in
>   associations.

Means it adds Functions by the name of the Table Model where you go `define('dict_Keys'...`
so add/set/get/ Dict_Key to Task.
That was the problem because I was using addDictkey instead of addDict_Key.
I hope it helps someone else in the Future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Frontend:** To get the data from the front end, just include the array as a property of the `data` you're posting. You might want to wrap the task specific properties in their own object as well:

```
this.$http.post('/api/tasks', {
    task: {
        user_id: $scope.selectUser,
        lang_id: $scope.selectLang,
        name: $scope.newTask
    },
    keys: [ 2, 5, 6 ]
});
```

**Backend:** Sequelize and other ORMs try to provide you with tools for using the relationships you've defined. Use them. You're already using [belongsToMany](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to-many/),  so you just need to do the next step of using your created `Task` object to create the `m:n` entries in `TaskKeys`:

```
...
return Task.create(req.body.task)
    .then(function(task) {
        return task.addProjects(req.body.keys);
    })
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
...
```

As for getting a task with keys, just use the `include` option:

```
...
return Task.findById(req.params.id, {
    include: [ { model: db.DictKey } ]
})
...
```

Comment: Thanks for Help. Frontend is working but Backend still Problems. If you could check Edit1 ?

Comment: What does the console show on the server when you get the 500 error for `return task.addTaskKeys(req.body.keys);`?

Comment: Console.log:
...doing first create of Task.create
then going taskadd
`POST /api/tasks 500 57.938 ms - 2`
BrwoserConsole Log:
`POST http://localhost:9000/api/tasks 500 (Internal Server Error)`
I tried with Hardcode values like
addTask(1);//1 is sure 100% existent in Key Table
Same Error

Comment: Can you set the `DEBUG` environment var to `*` before starting the server and try again? That should give more information... so like `DEBUG=* node server.js`

Comment: doing `DEBUG=express:* node index.js`, from Express Docs at Debuging.
Didnt change much the output.
But commenting `Task.create` out and only doing  
`return task.addKeys(1)` give the Error
Cannot read Property of addTask of undefined?

Comment: Well, yeah, commenting out the code that causes `task` to be defined will cause an `undefined` error when you try to use it. There's no further output on *the server console* when you enable debug?

Comment: If you check Edit2: you can see i tried several other things often is the Error is not a Function or can not read Property. Now just CopyPasted the userProject Example and it says as well addProject is not a Function.
After DEBUG=* the only output was the same Error 500 no more INfos to it.

Comment: Ive got it running....
It was a Problem with the Naming of the Functions `**Naming strategy**
By default sequelize will use the model name (the name passed to sequelize.define) to figure out the name of the model when used in associations.`
I was working allways with Task and DictKey the Instances of the Tables but Sequelize creates the Function with the declared name of the Table. So instead of adding addDictKey which i thought would be it was addDict_Key named after my Table. Editing my Question for Future users maybe with same Problem.

Comment: I Accept your Answer because it was right from beginning ;)

Answer (score 0):

`foreignKey` should be the same on both sides of the relation, to set the other key use the `otherKey` option.

Comment: Adding `otherKey` in
`// Tasks n:m Keys
db.DictKey.belongsToMany(db.Task, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey:'key_id',otherKey:'task_id'});
db.Task.belongsToMany(db.DictKey, { through: 'TaskKeys' , foreignKey: 'task_id',otherKey: 'key_id'});
` did not resolve the Problem. It remains as the same before with the Problem